# fatal error: opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: opencv, build

I am trying to build this code:https://github.com/yjxiong/dense_flow/tree/opencv-3.1

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have OpenCV 3.4 installed.

xfeatures2d.hpp can't be found on the system.

I have looked at many different problems on the internet, but couldn't find a solution.

the error as below:

```
/dense_flow/build$ cmake .. && make -j
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/yyk/ACTION/mmaction/third_party/dense_flow/build
Scanning dependencies of target denseflow
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/src/dense_warp_flow_gpu.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/src/dense_flow_gpu.cpp.o
/home/yyk/ACTION/mmaction/third_party/dense_flow/src/dense_warp_flow_gpu.cpp:12:10: fatal error: opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
/home/yyk/ACTION/mmaction/third_party/dense_flow/src/dense_flow_gpu.cpp:5:10: fatal error: opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/src/dense_warp_flow_gpu.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/src/dense_warp_flow_gpu.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/src/dense_flow_gpu.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/src/dense_flow_gpu.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:215: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/denseflow.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' faile
```

Any help is awesome!

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh U R warm hearted！And I solved it with the help of my colleague.

Comment: @yangyke, what was your solution? I've been struggling with a similar problem trying to install dense_flow

Comment: `xfeatures2d` is part of the **contrib** modules of OpenCV. you need to check out the contrib repo and set the cmake variable `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` to `opencv-contrib/modules`